# How to call a function of a parent class from another function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I guess that's the simple question. I'm new in `js`, especially in `Backbone.js`.

All I want to know is how I can refer to my function inside jquery function.

```
getLanguages: function() {

   ...

   return languages;
},

render: function() {

    ...

    $("input[type='checkbox']").bind("change", function() {

       // todo: getLanguages
    });

}
```

I tried to get languages via `this` but, of course, I got `checkbox` in this case.

**Edit:
It's so simple. Many thanks to all!!!**

Comment: that looks like an object, have u tried objName.functionName (obj.prop) ?

Comment: I updated my answer with Backbone-specific code that I recommend you examine. Storing a reference to `this` may solve your immediate problem, but it’s inelegant, and Backbone has built-in constructs to obviate the need for that inelegance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem in Javascript. You need to reference `this` inside a callback, but `this` changes to the element being bound to. A cheap way to do it:

```
render: function() {
    var that = this;

    $("input[type='checkbox']").bind("change", function() {
       that.getLanguages();
    });
}
```

`that` will stay defined as the `this` that `render` is defined on.

*However*, you’re using Backbone, and it has more suitable ways to handle this situation. I don’t know the name of your `Backbone.View` class, but here’s an [example adapted from the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

```
var DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "change input[type='checkbox']": "doSomething"
  },

  doSomething: function() {
    this.getLanguages(); # uses the correct this
  }
});
```

Calling `bind` inside `render` is not The Backbone Way. Backbone views are *made* to handle event delegation without the unfortunate need to pass `this` around.

Comment: +1 for `events`, using `events` also localizes everything to the view's `el` and that helps you keep your views self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

Save this object before bind change event in the scope of render function.

```
render: function() {

    var CurrentObj = this;

    $("input[type='checkbox']").bind("change", function() {
        CurrentObj.getLanguages();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the appropriate object into a local variable so from the event handler, you can still get to it:

```
getLanguages: function() {

   ...

   return languages;
},

render: function() {

    ...
    var self = this;

    $("input[type='checkbox']").bind("change", function() {
       var lang = self.getLanguages();
       ...
    });

}
```